# get radio button value on change not working

Tags: jquery

I use this code for get the value of radio button in jquery, my problem is when I click the option 1 it works fine but when I click on option 2 it not work. Please help!

```
<form>
Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 1">
Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 2">
</form>

$('#radio').change(function(){
var value = $( 'input[name=opt]:checked' ).val();
alert(value);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khizar067/h6ye7/

Answer (score 44):

Please try with the below Demo.

```
$('input[name=opt]').change(function(){
var value = $( 'input[name=opt]:checked' ).val();
alert(value);
});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/2/

Comment: You could also write it as
`var value = $( this ).val();`
To simplify the code a bit.

Comment: @DannyG Oh yeah using the "this" extra points for keeping it real!

Comment: If you're using "this", you might as well just use `var value = this.value` instead of making another jQuery call.

Answer (score 13):

`ID` of elements [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), if there are multiple elements with same id then the id selector will return only the first element. so in your case the change event handler is added to only the first radio element

```
<form>
Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 1">
Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 2">
</form>
```

and

```
//or $('.radio') as the selector
var $radios = $('input[name=opt]').change(function () {
    var value = $radios.filter(':checked').val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vmcnf/)

Answer (score 5):

The `id` should be unique, try using class instead:

Html:

```
<form>
    Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 1">
    Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Option 2">
</form>
```

Js:

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
    var value = $( this ).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/3/)

Answer (score 4):

```
 <form id="abcd">
     Option 1<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 1">
     Option 2<input type="radio" name="opt" id="radio" value="Option 2">
 </form>

$('#abcd').on('change','input[name=opt]:checked',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

1. id="abcd" is a selector for uniqueness in your whole html code if you have multiple forms it will help to get specific form.
2. in jQuery  for on read the following  documentation
   Visit http://api.jquery.com/on/
   'change' is the event if this event is occured anytime in the page for the selector "abcd" jquery will search 'input[name=opt]:checked' i.e input type whose name is opt and will check if it is checked and function() is a handler which will handle the event means you can you write your logic here...

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this is help you, if you use use multiple radio button then you don't need to get id or class of element you simply get element property by there tag name..

There are several example on this

1.By tag name(All radio button can be select)

```
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        var value = $( 'input[name=opt]:checked' ).val();
        alert(value);
    });
```

2.By class name(Multiple radio button can be select)

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function(){
        var value = $( 'input[name=opt]:checked' ).val();
        alert(value);
    });
```

3.By id (one radio button select only)

```
$('#radiobutton').change(function(){
    var value = $( 'input[name=opt]:checked' ).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ye7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name=opt]').on('change',function () {
    alert($(this).filter(':checked').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  First Option<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="First Option">
  Second Option<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Second Option">
</form>
```